# How to mock a method that returns a mock object which is cast

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

**How to mock a method that returns a mock object which is cast.**

I have a method which returns a mock object which is cast from an `Object` into `SomeClass` then calls a method on `SomeClass`.

The problem is the method `getBean("SomeClass")` returns an `Object` and not `SomeClass` so mocking

`when(mockApplicationContext.getBean("SomeClass")).thenReturn(mockSomeClass);`

dosent work as the return type is wrong and mocking

`when(mockApplicationContext.getBean("SomeClass")).thenReturn(mockObject);`

dosent work as the method called on `SomeClass` dosent exist and I cant mock `SomeClass`.

How can this be mocked?

**Method to test.**

```
    public void anyMethod() {       

    // code omitted

    ( (SomeClass) getApplicationContext().getBean("SomeClass") ).someMethod(anArgument);

    // ...
}
```

**Test Method.**

```
@Test
public void testAnyMethod() {

    // ...

    SomeClass mockSomeClass = mock(SomeClass.class);
    when(mockSomeClass.someMethod(anArgument)).thenReturn(someResult);

    ApplicationContext mockApplicationContext = mock(ApplicationContext.class);
    when(mockApplicationContext.getBean("SomeClass")).thenReturn(mockSomeClass);

    PowerMockito.doReturn(mockApplicationContext).when(GetContext.class, "getApplicationContext");

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a code error there (at least in the snippet), should it be `when(mockSomeClass.someMethod(anArgument)).thenReturn(someResult);`

Comment: Also it seems the code is mixing PowerMockito and Mockito API. I don't think PowerMockito is useful in this test.

Comment: Anyway I don't see any problem with returning `SomeClass` (be it a mock or not) from `applicationContext.getBean()` as SomeClass inherits `Object` anyway

Comment: As a side note I would strongly advise you to not mock types you don't own !

Comment: @Brice PowerMockito is needed as `getApplicationContext()` is not visible. "...not mock types you don't own !" How would you test it then?

Comment: I don't know exactly what the test is trying to achieve, but usually where there's an external dependency (such as Spring) I would **as much as possible** try to use their object. Otherwise stubbing external dependencies hides actual behavior (that may change with versions and other factors), or even not be the same, the tests pass, but not when the artifact is deployed. Here if `getApplicationContext` is private it's for a reason, what if this **internal** method change in some way ?

Comment: @Brice `getApplicationContext()` is protected and being called by a subclass in the src but obviously the test is not a subclass hence PowerMock. It simply returns the application context. The object returned is my object. The result of the line above is not that relevant to the test and the overall behaviour but without mocking the test throws NPE.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand clearly the problem you are facing. But imho what the test should be aiming is something similar to @Steve's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your method implementation slightly to use the type-safe methods:

```
public void anyMethod() {       

    // code omitted

    getApplicationContext().getBean("SomeClass", SomeClass.class).someMethod(anArgument);

    // ...
}
```

then your test class changes only a little to:

```
@Test
public void testAnyMethod() {

    // ...

    SomeClass mockSomeClass = mock(SomeClass.class);
    when(mockSomeClass).someMethod(anArgument).thenReturn(someResult);

    // The problem is that .getBean("SomeClass") returns Object.class which is then cast
    // to SomeClass in anyMethod. If I return an Object then someMethod(anArgument) dosent exist

    ApplicationContext mockApplicationContext = mock(ApplicationContext.class);
    when(mockApplicationContext.getBean("SomeClass", SomeClass.class)).thenReturn(mockSomeClass);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of doing what you want - you need to specify the behaviour of the mocked class during your set up:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = mock(ApplicationContext.class);
List<String> mockList = mock(List.class);
when(ctx.getBean("XYZ")).thenReturn(mockList);
when(mockList.get(0)).thenReturn("ABC");  // Setting up the behaviour!

// ctx.getBean("XYZ").get(0); // can't call List methods here

// Cast and call in one
System.out.println(((List<String>) ctx.getBean("XYZ")).get(0)); // Prints "ABC"

// .. or cast into a new reference
List<String> list = (List<String>) ctx.getBean("XYZ");
System.out.println(list.get(0));  // Also prints "ABC"
```